# Display string array macOS Xamarin application

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac, monomac

I have a generic collection `List<(my own type)>`.
How can I display a simple array of strings to not define my own cells (`NSCollectionViewItem`)?
Which control is best for this?

Comment: What is the intended use? You say you want to display the strings. But a control implies user interaction. Please be more specific. Also you tagged both xamarin.ios and xamarin.mac Which is it? They are different platforms

Comment: I need to display data (a list of rows) that the user can select, but not edit. He clicks on one of the lines, then by pressing one of the two buttons he can perform the action (delete this line or overwrite  or something else)

Comment: Xamarin.Ios and Xamarin.Mac this is .Net platforms, which i creating my MacOS app, I think that the way to display such a list is not much different in ios and mac

Comment: I create both xamarin.ios and xamarin.mac apps and they have a different UI layer (UIKit vs AppKit). There are allot of similarities but also allot of differences.

Comment: Ok, i changed tags

Comment: NSTableView would be best probably. But you will either have to use interface builder and hookup the textField of NSTableCellView OR doing all from code have to subclass NSTableCellView